# How to play a video from URL in Action View in android

Tags: android, actionview

i am working on an app, in which i want to play a video intenting ACTION VIEW from URL receiving from WEB SERVER, i am getting unsupportable file format. my code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            videostring = ib.getVideostring();
            Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///https://" + videostring.get(0));
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*");
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Check the media file for supported formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: This is mp4 format,,, so no issue in that i think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///https://" + videostring.get(0));`

to

```
Uri data = Uri.parse("https://" + videostring.get(0));
```